# Heuristic reasoning on the prevalence of prime numbers $ 5 \pmod 6 $ over those $ 1 \pmod 6 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If  $p$ prime then

$p \neq |-1+6 \cdot (6 \cdot a \cdot b+a-b)| \quad \forall \quad a\in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\} ,b \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$

Analyzing the composite numbers:

$n_c=|-1+6 \cdot (6 \cdot a \cdot b+a-b)| \quad : \quad a\in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\} ,b \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$

it can be seen that if $a$ and $b$ are of opposite sign then $ n_c \equiv 1 \pmod 6 $ but if $a$ and $b$ are of equal sign then $ n_c \equiv 5 \pmod 6 $.

From the formula we see that for each value $ |6 \cdot a \cdot b| $ in the first case two elements $ ($ obtained by adding the values ​​$ \pm (|a| + |b|) $ to  $ 6 \cdot a \cdot b $$ )$ are added to the composite numbers $ n_c \equiv 1 \pmod 6 $ with $ a $ and $ b $ of opposite sign.

instead in the second case $ n_c \equiv 5 \pmod 6 $ the two additional elements are obtained by adding the values ​​$\pm (|a| - |b|)$ to  $ 6 \cdot a \cdot b$.

In particular in the second case for $a = b$ to composite numbers $ n_c \equiv 5 \pmod 6 $ only one element is added compared to those $ n_c \equiv 1 \pmod 6 $ in which two elements are added, for this reason for a given value $n$ the composite numbers $ n_c \equiv 1 \pmod 6 $ less than $n$ are greater than those $ 5 \pmod 6 $.

Is this reasoning correct and can it be useful?

**Edit**

Verified up to $3 \cdot 10^6$ that the remainder upon dividing the primes by $6$ gives $5$ more often than $1$.

According to this analysis, given a certain value $ n $ there should be a link between the difference in the number of primes $ \pi_ {5,6} (n) - \pi_ {1,6} (n) $ and the number of primes minor of $ \sqrt n $ or when $ | -1 + 6 \cdot a | $ and / or $ | 1 + 6 \cdot b | $ are prime, as plotted in  figure:

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias, modulo 3, says there is a bias.

Comment: @Arthur for $ a = b $ $ n_c = 3 \pmod 4 $

Comment: But on the long run, the ratio of the number of primes of both types , will tend to exactly $\frac{1}{2}$ , although numerical analysis does this usually not back up. This holds for every fixed $a$ , if we consider the number of primes of the form $an+b$. For every possible $b<a$, the ratio of the number of primes will be $\frac{1}{\varphi(a)}$

Comment: In the prime "race" between $4k+1$-primes and $4k+3$-primes , the lead switches infinite many often, and I guess this is also the case for $6k+1$ and $6k+5$ , but I am not sure.

Comment: I think it is more appropriate to think considering the numbers $ 1 \pmod 6 $ and $ 5 \pmod 6 $ however if you want to examine the behavior of the numbers $ 1 \pmod 4 $ and $ 3 \pmod 4 $ you can proceed in the same way using the equation $ n_c = | -1 + 4 \cdot (4 \cdot a \cdot b + a-b) | $

Comment: You might enjoy reading Granville and Martin, Prime number races, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408319

Comment: Have you had a look at that paper?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes thanks. But I wanted to understand if this reasoning, certainly valid only for not very large values ​​of n, is correct.